# Bootstrap carousel controls causing error

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, carousel, slice

I'm using carousel.js, but when I use the controls, it starts to get buggy.

What I've noticed is:

- When the autoplay showed all images and wants to show the first one again, it shows the first one for 0.5 seconds and returns to the last image and stays there.
- The same goes for using the next button, it starts to bug at the last image (same as autoplay).
- The prev button works fine, when I use that it doesn't show any problems at all.
- When I remove the buttons, it works fine, no errors at all (Autoplay works fine).

Now the error that shows in console is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined, but I don't think this is the core of the error.
Because what I've noticed in inspect element is that when the error occurs, none of the images in the slides have the class: 'active' anymore, so the code won't work anymore. But I'm not sure what the cause of this is.

This is the code from my controls:

```
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-{$id}" data-slide="prev" role="button">
    <span class="icon-arrow_left_nav icon-arrow-left2""></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-{$id}" data-slide="next" role="button">
    <span class="icon-arrow_right_nav icon-arrow-right2"></span>
</a>
```

And this is the code from the carousel.js file (standard)

```
/* ========================================================================
 * Bootstrap: carousel.js v3.2.0
 * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel
 * ========================================================================
 * Copyright 2011-2014 Twitter, Inc.
 * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
 * ======================================================================== */


+function ($) {
    'use strict';
    // CAROUSEL CLASS DEFINITION
    // =========================

    var Carousel = function (element, options) {
        this.$element = $(element).on('keydown.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.keydown, this))
        this.$indicators = this.$element.find('.carousel-indicators')
        this.options = options
        this.paused =
            this.sliding =
                this.interval =
                    this.$active =
                        this.$items = null

        this.options.pause == 'hover' && this.$element
            .on('mouseenter.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.pause, this))
            .on('mouseleave.bs.carousel', $.proxy(this.cycle, this))
    }

    Carousel.VERSION = '3.2.0'

    Carousel.DEFAULTS = {
        interval: 5000,
        pause: 'hover',
        wrap: true
    }

    Carousel.prototype.keydown = function (e) {
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                this.prev();
                break
            case 39:
                this.next();
                break
            default:
                return
        }

        e.preventDefault()
    }

    Carousel.prototype.cycle = function (e) {
        e || (this.paused = false)

        this.interval && clearInterval(this.interval)

        this.options.interval
        && !this.paused
        && (this.interval = setInterval($.proxy(this.next, this), this.options.interval))

        return this
    }

    Carousel.prototype.getItemIndex = function (item) {
        this.$items = item.parent().children('div.item')
        return this.$items.index(item || this.$active)
    }

    Carousel.prototype.to = function (pos) {
        var that = this
        var activeIndex = this.getItemIndex(this.$active = this.$element.find('div.item.active'))

        if (pos > (this.$items.length - 1) || pos < 0) return

        if (this.sliding)       return this.$element.one('slid.bs.carousel', function () {
            that.to(pos)
        }) // yes, "slid"
        if (activeIndex == pos) return this.pause().cycle()

        return this.slide(pos > activeIndex ? 'next' : 'prev', $(this.$items[pos]))
    }

    Carousel.prototype.pause = function (e) {
        e || (this.paused = true)

        if (this.$element.find('.next, .prev').length && $.support.transition) {
            this.$element.trigger($.support.transition.end)
            this.cycle(true)
        }

        this.interval = clearInterval(this.interval)

        return this
    }

    Carousel.prototype.next = function () {
        if (this.sliding) return
        return this.slide('next')
    }

    Carousel.prototype.prev = function () {
        if (this.sliding) return
        return this.slide('prev')
    }

    Carousel.prototype.slide = function (type, next) {
        var $active = this.$element.find('div.item.active')
        var $next = next || $active[type]()
        var isCycling = this.interval
        var direction = type == 'next' ? 'left' : 'right'
        var fallback = type == 'next' ? 'first' : 'last'
        var that = this
        if (!$next.length) {
            if (!this.options.wrap) return
            $next = this.$element.find('div.item')[fallback]()
        }

        if ($next.hasClass('active')) return (this.sliding = false)

        var relatedTarget = $next[0]
        var slideEvent = $.Event('slide.bs.carousel', {
            relatedTarget: relatedTarget,
            direction: direction
        })
        this.$element.trigger(slideEvent)
        if (slideEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) return

        this.sliding = true

        isCycling && this.pause()

        if (this.$indicators.length) {
            this.$indicators.find('.active').removeClass('active')
            var $nextIndicator = $(this.$indicators.children()[this.getItemIndex($next)])
            $nextIndicator && $nextIndicator.addClass('active')
        }

        var slidEvent = $.Event('slid.bs.carousel', {relatedTarget: relatedTarget, direction: direction}) // yes, "slid"
        if ($.support.transition && this.$element.hasClass('slide')) {
            $next.addClass(type)
            $next[0].offsetWidth // force reflow
            $active.addClass(direction)
            $next.addClass(direction)
            $active
                .one('bsTransitionEnd', function () {
                    $next.removeClass([type, direction].join(' ')).addClass('active')
                    $active.removeClass(['active', direction].join(' '))
                    that.sliding = false
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        that.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
                    }, 0)
                })
                .emulateTransitionEnd($active.css('transition-duration').slice(0, -1) * 1000)
        } else {
            $active.removeClass('active')
            $next.addClass('active')
            this.sliding = false
            this.$element.trigger(slidEvent)
        }

        isCycling && this.cycle()

        return this
    }


    // CAROUSEL PLUGIN DEFINITION
    // ==========================

    function Plugin(option) {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            var data = $this.data('bs.carousel')
            var options = $.extend({}, Carousel.DEFAULTS, $this.data(), typeof option == 'object' && option)
            var action = typeof option == 'string' ? option : options.slide

            if (!data) $this.data('bs.carousel', (data = new Carousel(this, options)))
            if (typeof option == 'number') data.to(option)
            else if (action) data[action]()
            else if (options.interval) data.pause().cycle()
        })
    }

    var old = $.fn.carousel

    $.fn.carousel = Plugin
    $.fn.carousel.Constructor = Carousel


    // CAROUSEL NO CONFLICT
    // ====================

    $.fn.carousel.noConflict = function () {
        $.fn.carousel = old
        return this
    }


    // CAROUSEL DATA-API
    // =================

    $(document).on('click.bs.carousel.data-api', '[data-slide], [data-slide-to]', function (e) {
        var href
        var $this = $(this)
        var $target = $($this.attr('data-target') || (href = $this.attr('href')) && href.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]+$)/, '')) // strip for ie7
        if (!$target.hasClass('carousel')) return
        var options = $.extend({}, $target.data(), $this.data())
        var slideIndex = $this.attr('data-slide-to')
        if (slideIndex) options.interval = false

        Plugin.call($target, options)

        if (slideIndex) {
            $target.data('bs.carousel').to(slideIndex)
        }

        e.preventDefault()
    })

    $(window).on('load', function () {
        $('[data-ride="carousel"]').each(function () {
            var $carousel = $(this)
            Plugin.call($carousel, $carousel.data())
        })
    })

}(jQuery);
```